# Phone dropped in water - Now screen won't turn off (Samsung Galaxy S2 (SII))?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, screen, hardware, water-damage, wakelock

I currently have a `Samsung Galaxy SII (S2)(I9100)` that got dropped in water. I took the phone apart (removed the screws on the back and properly took the back off) and left it to dry in a warm place overnight.

The phone works absolutely fine as you'd expect it to, but it now has this weird issue where the `screen won't turn off` at all, whenever I press the power button to turn the screen off, it comes straight back on again. If I let it go to sleep with it's own "timout" it just comes back on straight away also.

It has been `factory reset` and still does it. It has `stock Android that came with the device`, `never rooted` or had `custom ROMS` installed.

Here's a video of the problem actually happening:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4UViRT64Ss

I assume it *has* to be a hardware issue from the water damage, but has anyone experienced this? **Is it likely I'd be able to change any of the parts inside to try and fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The water evaporating has left now undissolved mineral ions on your phone (ions conduct electricity).Now electricity doesn't go as designed.Also heat cycles will possibly change chemical and physical structure of your hardware.The more you use it the more likely something will get worse

Instead of drying to get rid of water and leave the ions on your phone you should have hoovered the water being cautious not to discharge static electricity to the phone (even though theoretically almost everyone should have damaged their hardware with static many times in their lives it somehow never happens)

Now maybe you should clean it properly (isopropyl alcohol should work the purer the better at least 99%)

The better way to clean it is with bathing it in the alcohol and use ultrasound at the same time which some more professional phonerepairers do with special machines.(You can find some good replacements of the machines for about 50usd)
It most often works without ultrasounding but the ultrasound method is much better and fixes the performance of water damaged phone more.

Comment: Switching it off and completely submerging it (including the battery) in isopropyl alcohol for 15 minutes, then taking it out and letting it dry for 24 hours fixed it! Thank you so much for answering!

Comment: @BT643 I'm interested if you submerged it completely disassembled and did you wipe it with something?

Comment: I didn't completely disassemble it, I just removed the back battery cover, and removed the battery (but also put it in the alcohol with the phone). I didn't wipe it, just took it out and left it on the side for 24 hours to dry. Shocked that it fixed it! It was just a "first attempt" :)

Comment: I had same issue with my Samsung S3 mini as desrcibed here and did the same: 15 min into Isopropylalcohol, then I left it on the air 2 days for drying and now it works.
Thanks a lot for help and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try an app to turn the screen off, such as this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.katecca.screenofflock&hl=en

Sounds like you've done well to only have this little damage. Perhaps even this will recover in time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the [Screen Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cmcm.screenoff&hl=en) app solved the problem. It allows the user to turn off the screen without pressing the power button.

Answer (score 0):

change the charging connector in the phone.

Comment: and how would that help ? can you explain further ?

Answer (score 0):

FIXED: I am a Phone/PC Technician, I just fixed a customer's phone, the issue was the screen wont turn off via power button nor when the phone goes to standby it would come back on... The Samsung Galaxy J5 fell in his toilet which he quickly grabbed it out.. 
The FIX was to remove the board and use clear rubbing alcohol and a small flat head screwdriver to scrape and to clean all contact points which had some white corrosion, even the internal metal edge that grounds against the chassis and board. Screw phone back together ensuring all contact points are touching then test to see if all is working.  All the best to you!